# How do you record a message on windows phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

How does Shazam do it? It records the messages and then gets the sound track.

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean? How does the music recognition work or how does the recording work?

Well, here are my assumptions:

1. [Using microphone](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikeormond/archive/2010/08/27/xna-from-silverlight-on-windows-phone-7-the-microphone.aspx) it records the sound.
2. Caluculate the hash value of the sound - the FFT of singal and some special kind of hash  function that gives you the key.
3. Send the key to the server using webservice.
4. Server does the search of the database to find the song.
5. After a wile get the result via [push notification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402558%28v=vs.92%29.aspx).

Comment: You don't use push notifications to get something to the server. You use for example webservices for that. Push is done to send something from the server to the phone if you want.

Comment: Thank you, I was looking for recording the message. Is there a library to convert the recorded message into text. I would like to save this text in the database.

Comment: You should ask this in a seperate question ?